# Maven: How can I have a module with same name under two different modules?

Tags: java, maven

Consider this structure

```
project
       pom.xml
       component1/
                 pom.xml
                 persistence/pom.xml
                 business/pom.xml
                 rest/pom.xml
       component2/
                 pom.xml
                 persistence/pom.xml
                 business/pom.xml
                 rest/pom.xml
```

When I try to do this, I get `NullPointerException`

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Can I not have a structure like this? I am using `Maven 3.2.1`

This is how `component2/pom.xml` looks

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>component2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This is same as `component1/pom.xml` **except** parent

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>component1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

When I try to have a different module name, it works

Comment: both of them have different group id right ?

Comment: they should have different group id,can you try addine one more level in naming ?

Comment: not clear if I understood, could you please explain it?

Comment: if you can have different group id for both `persistence` package

Comment: The simple things is: The artifactId must be unique within a groupId. So if you need having two artifactId with the same name you need to have a different groupId otherwise it's simply not possible. The same is like in java with the java classes within packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jigar-joshi has indicated, maven needs a way to distinguish between the `persistence` module of `component1` and `persistence` module of `component2`.  The way it does is by by the combination of `groupId` and `artifactId`.  This combination needs to be unique for each `persistence` module (or `business` and `rest` for that matter).

So, either each `persistence` needs to have a unique `groupId` (say `com.org.component1` and `com.org.component2`) or a unique `artifactId` (`component1-persistence` and `component2-persistence`).

Answer (score 0):

Not only maven gets will be confused with actual layering of your project, but some day you will get lost with both modules and you won't know which one is this or that.

So as @Raghuram pointed out you will need a **unique** identifier for each module, thus by having a unique *groupId* or unique *artifcatId* (Within scope of your project and even respecting other artifacts or you will get weird conflicts).

This is for *uniqueness* purpose, but some conventions should be followed and you will automatically get your self out of any troubles that could be caused by modules/projects naming:

- *goupId*: A **universally unique identifier for a project**. It is normal to use a fully-qualified package name to distinguish it from other projects with a similar name (eg. org.apache.maven).
- *artifactId*: The identifier for this artifact that **is unique within the group given by the group ID**.

Just follow those lines and you'll be not even safe but producing packages respecting practice rules.